# Composer doesn't autoload custom package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

**acknowledgement**:
First of all this is my first post for help, as i went trough a lot of articles on stackoverflow and other resources and just could not find solution.

Problem sounds familiar but i just can't figure it out, maybe because im stuck on it for 2 days now. Another note, this is my first package so yes im not 100% sure what im doing.

**Structure:**

```
- laravel-project 
    - ...
    - packages
        - my-custom-package
            - src
                - MyCustomPackageServiceProvider.php
            - composer.json
    - public
    - resources
    - routes
    - ...
    - composer.json
```

So it is basic Laravel 5.8 + inside added package folder for local package devolment (it has been moved to repo as well)

Current Code (simplified as its actual work project):

**File:** laravel-project/packages/my-custom-package/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "company/my-custom-package",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "ext-curl": "*"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "email": "jsmith@test.tv"
        }
    ],
    "autoload" : {
        "prs-4": {
            "Company\\MyCustomPackage\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

**File:** laravel-project/packages/my-custom-package/src/MyCustomPackageServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyCustomPackage;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyCustomPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/routes/web.php');
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/database/migrations');
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }

}
```

**File:** laravel-project/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "~/testlaravel/packages/my-custom-package",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.3",
        "company/my-custom-package": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "prs-4": {
            "Company\\MyCustomPackage\\": "~/testlaravel/packages/my-custom-package/src"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** ~/testlaravel/ is folder path inside Vagrant machine for project originaly url was "packages/my-custom-package" buti changed for this extended version just in pure attempt of making it work.

**File:** config/app.php (added service provider)

```
Company\MyCustomPackage\MyCustomPackageServiceProvider::class
```

Issue:
First i made this thing localy and it worked i was following for quick setup instructions from
"*Create Laravel Composer Package from scratch to upload on packagist*" Author: *Bitfumes*, and package worked, I could run composer update, then i added to app.php my package and i could run custom route and it all worked.
After that i moved package to git repo, and required it in same way only changed "repositories" field to

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.fulllink.co:john/my-custom-package.git"
        }
    ]
```

and when you run composer update, you can see that afterwards inside vendor/ files you have Company folder with package inside it, BUT if you leave config/app.php service provider it starts to complain that there is
  `*Class 'Company\MyCustomPackage\MyCustomPackageServiceProvider' not fo   und*`

After some f*** around i found out that yes my autoload_classmap (cant remember original post) did not contain my package , so today i decided to try again local and see the difference, does it been added to map file, and now i get same error when requiring local package and i can't make it work anymore.

I been deleting vendor folder and lock file , composer dump-autoload, but that doesnt help. Im just thinking is thgere anything else supercached?

**!!UPDATE!!**
Im not even more confused. In composer.json (project one i tested on actual project repo now where is required another 2 local git repos). So i have now 4 packages in vendor/Company/{4 packages} , i compared all 4 package composer.json and i can't find any major difference but all of them have been loaded to autoload mapping except mine. Only major difference i can see, those two packages doesnt use ServiceProvider.php file , but i dont see how that impacts or changes things.

Comment: In your Laravel's root composer.json autoload-dev, why put a path with `~` instead a normal relative path? Does composer really support absolute path?

Comment: Have you try moving your `autoload-dev` contents into `autoload`?

Comment: @KoalaYeung i think i mentioned in description that originaly it was  "packages/my-custom-package" and actually i tried different paths, so Im not sure about absoluth path as it was relative one

Comment: @KoalaYeung actually i did not try that, as it was working before on autoload-dev, however now i have question , if i require package from git, and packages composer.json has prs-4 autoload described , should it not autoload from there or it does only when it is via packagist, as (it did work now) i thought i need set autoload in each package

Comment: If your packages is installed from `composer require` or otherwise pre-defined in `composer.json`, composer would download it, read the package's composer.json then do autoload accordingly (no need to add your own "autoload" or "autoload-dev". The install path would, however, be `vendor/` instead of `packages/`.

Comment: If you want to change the default installation path of packages, you'd probably need to define `extra.install-paths` in your root `composer.json`, as described [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md).

Comment: @KoalaYeung actually that what i mean, because I'm requiring package via 
```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.localstuff.co:kvanags/my-custom-package.git"
        }
```
it was just i returned to local path as that was original way. So package should be installed from vendor/ foulder

Comment: I don't think I fully get what you want. The "repositories" value defines where a package is installed **from**. The `extra.install-paths` value defines where a package is installed **to**, which would be "vendor/" by default. You wouldn't normally need to define `extra.install-paths`. And your package wouldn't normally installed to the "packages/" folder.

Comment: @KoalaYeung but thats exactly what i mean, I did package in local path and it worked (then for some reason stopped, but moving to autoload made it work) but i want and i did move package to GIT repo, from where im requiring it via VSC, so package is loaded up in vendors/ folder as i said in description, it just doesnt autoload

Answer (score 0):

You did 90% of the work correctly, so here is a concise answer for anyone who is facing this issue, I just tested this with Laravel 8.8 but I'm confident it will work with Laravel v10 as well.

### 1️⃣ First step

In root `composer.json` of your Laravel project have these 2 changes.

1. Require your custom library like so:

   `"company/my-custom-package": "dev-main"`
   if you are on legacy default git branch naming then use `dev-master`

---

2. Add repositories to the end of the same file like so:

   ```json
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "path",
           "url": "packages/my-custom-package/",
           "options": {
               "symlink": true
           }
       }
   ]
   ```

   Where `packages` is a directory residing next to your root `composer.json`.

---

### 2️⃣ Second step

Now inside your custom package, let's say `packages/my-custom-package/composer.json` make sure to have these two obvious configs.

1. Autoload, dah! Directory where your SP reside

   ```json
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\MyCustomPackage\\": "src/"
        }
    },
   ```

---

2. Now "extras" so we can enable Laravel to auto-discover our package, right?

   ```json
   "extra": {
       "laravel": {
           "providers": [
               "Company\\MyCustomPackage\\FooServiceProvider"
           ],
           "aliases": {
               "Foo": "Company\\MyCustomPackage\\FooFacade"
           }
       }
   },
   ```